# Is there a more convenient way to handle a Q promise result when saving a mongoose model?

Tags: mongoose, q

We have a recurring pattern in our application when persisting an instance of a mongoose model to the data, which looks like this:

```
var newClient = new Client.model( data );

Q.ninvoke( newClient, "save" )
  .then( function( newEntity, numberAffected ) {
           numberAffected = newEntity[ 1 ];
           newEntity = newEntity[ 0 ];
  } );
```

Usually, [`save`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) would accept a callback which takes 3 arguments. The first error argument is stripped off by Q and optionally handled in a `fail` callback.

The remaining parameters are passed to the `then` callback as an array. We now break that array apart to give meaning to the entries, but this seems a little inconvenient.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're now using [mongoose-q](https://github.com/iolo/mongoose-q). The same code now looks like this:

```
var newClient = new Client.model( data );

newClient.saveQ()
  .then( function( newEntity, numberAffected ) {
  } );
```